# Disable a RadioButtonList Item - Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, radiobuttonlist

In an ASP.NET 2.0 project I've got a `RadioButtonList`. I'd like to disable one of the items in this list, but when I change the `Enable` property of an item to `false` it just wrappers the item with a span instead of disabling the `Input` when rendered to Html:

```
<span disabled="disabled">
   <input id="ctl00_RadioGroup_2" type="radio" value="OK" name="ctl00$RadioGroup">
   <label for="ctl00_RadioGroup_2">Ok</label>
</span>
```

This works Fine on **IE9** but on **FF4** the radio button is still enabled.

Any quick solution for this issue? 
Or is the only way would be some Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span-tag doesn't have a disable attribute. check [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4)
it will be better to use javascript to set disable  to each radio input element